# Single Result From SUM With MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, sum

Looked all over.  Can't find an answer.  PHP docs not clear (to me).

I'm doing a simple MySQL sum through `mysqli->query`. How can I get the result with MySQLi like `mysql_result`?

Comment: Are you able to get the results from a regular query with mysqli? The fact that you're using sum() shouldn't change anything.

Comment: assuming something like this: `$res=mysqli_query($dbh,"select sum(field) from table1"); if (FALSE === $res) die("select sum failed");` follow up with `$row = mysqli_fetch_row($res); $sum = $row[0];`

Comment: Ironically, I only have experience with arrays using mysqli_fetch_assoc.  How would I access the single result?  Using the column that was summed?  An alias?  Thank-you very much for your help.

Comment: @tamouse Using "$row = mysqli_fetch_row($res);"  gives "Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given"

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy did you test the result from mysqli_query to see if it is FALSE? It will return FALSE if there was an error in the query.

Comment: @tamouse Yup, bad sql statement there.  Your solution worked.  Sure you don't want to mark as real answer to get the check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whatever is given in the SELECT statement to mysqli_query is going to return a mysql_result type if the query was successful. So if you have a SELECT statement such as:

```
SELECT sum(field) FROM table1
```

you still need to fetch the row with the result, and the value of the sum() function will be the only entry in the row array:

```
$res = mysqli_query($dbh,'SELECT sum(field) FROM table1');
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
$sum = $row[0];
```

Answer (score 10):

It's best if you used an alias for your SUM:

```
SELECT SUM(`field`) as `sum` FROM `table_name`
```

And then, you'll be able to fetch the result normally by accessing the first result row's `$row['sum']`.