# How do I get the SUM visible?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sum

I am new into php and mysql and also on this website. So I hope I do everything good.

I am trying to get the SUM of some values in a column. But I don't see any result of this on the website. I am trying for a week now searched a lot of information and topics but so far no result at all.  So I would like to ask a favor to you in the hope someone can see what I do wrong.

This is what I have now.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","1234","dbname");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT SUM(Bedrag) FROM `Uitdraai` WHERE Datum BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-03-01'");
if (FALSE === $res) die("Select sum failed: ".mysqli_error);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($res);
$sum = $row[0];

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I already tried almost every option also on the following pages but so far no luck. I just get my regular webpage only without the answer.

[Get sum of MySQL column in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808522/get-sum-of-mysql-column-in-php?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[Single Result From SUM With MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655734/single-result-from-sum-with-mysqli?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I will be really thankful!

Comment: `var_dump($sum)` show what?

Comment: you don't echo the result  try  `echo $row[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(Bedrag) AS value_sum  FROM `Uitdraai` WHERE Datum BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-03-01;
```

In the PHP code, try this:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT SUM(Bedrag) AS value_sum  FROM `Uitdraai` WHERE Datum BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-03-01'); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
$sum = $row['value_sum'];
echo $sum;
```

Using PDO (mysql_query is depreciated)

```
$stmt = $handler->prepare("SELECT SUM(Bedrag) AS value_sum  FROM `Uitdraai` WHERE Datum BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-03-01");
$stmt->execute();

$row = $handler->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$sum = $row->value_sum;
echo $sum;
```

Comment: The OP is using mysqli, not mysql or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

You should know that mysql_connect is depreciated from **php 7 or upper**. For this you need to use **mysqli** or **pdo** for interacting with the server.

you can try below code for getting sum from the database.

```
    $con = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(Bedrag) AS value_sum  FROM Uitdraai WHERE Datum BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-03-01'";

    $stmt = $con->query($sql);
   if($stmt){
       $result = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
       echo $result['value_sum'];
    }
```