# adding values in an array from SQL result

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I'm trying to put the user_value in an array if the affiliate_id=50. Then add up the array with the sum function. The issue is the array only has one of the user values inside it.

My question is how do I add all the user_values together (in an array) WHERE the affiliate_id=50?

Currently only one user_value is added to the array.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZZ3V.jpg

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT user_value FROM active_users WHERE affiliate_id=50"); 
$affiliate_total_earnt = array(mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql));



echo array_sum($affiliate_total_earnt);
```

Comment: each call to mysqli_fetch_assoc fetches only one row (which is why you see it used in a while loop), use `$sql->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)` instead

Comment: Note that the SQL query can return directly the sum: `SELECT sum(user_value) FROM active_users WHERE affiliate_id=50 GROUP BY affiliate_id`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte makes a good point you might as well do in the query `SELECT SUM(user_value) as affiliate_total_earnt FROM ...`

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone  Thanks for your help. Worked a charm, appreciate it. :)

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte cheers for your help. Works just as I wanted. Thanks very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Single Result From SUM With MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655734/single-result-from-sum-with-mysqli)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can summarize values directly in MySQL:

```php
$query = "SELECT sum(user_value) as sum FROM active_users WHERE affiliate_id=50";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
$affiliate_total_earn = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)['sum'];
    
echo "Affiliate total earn: " . $affiliate_total_earn;
```

Try code here [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=287aa273766b364e999f75483cee6518&sqlses=978b21959f168595b5766b95f0fd5a56&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)